# dataTable that slides down when plotting

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a dataTable output on a page in Shiny, in which I have enabled row selection:

```
 output$table <- renderDataTable({datasetInput()},options = list(pageLength = 10,bLengthChange=F,bInfo=0),callback = "function(table) {
table.on('click.dt', 'tr', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
Shiny.onInputChange('rows',
table.rows('.selected').indexes().toArray());
});  
}"
```

What I would like to do, is use the users row selection, take the value from the first column, which is an ID, and use that ID to search a df and plot a result.

That I can implement.

But what I would like, is the ability to slide the table down the page to reveal the plot when the row is selected, and when its deselected, hide the plot and slide the table back up the page.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: This might help https://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02

Comment: Not quite, though it is helpful thanks. I want the entire table to slide down the page, so I have room to display a plot.